# How to split a numpy array at a specific index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say there is a numpy array

```
arr = np.array([[1, 4, 2, 4, 7],
                [6, 7, 9, 2, 8]])
```

I want to split this array in two, but at a specific index i.e [1][1]
So it would be split from the number 7 in the second row onwards and the new arrays would be

```
arr1= [1, 4, 2, 4, 7],
      [6, 7]
arr2 = [9, 2, 8]
```

Is this at all possible using numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a previous answer, this is not possible with `numpy` but you can do it easily by converting your array to a list :

```
arr = arr.tolist()

i,j = 1,1

arr1 = arr[:i+1]
arr1[-1] = arr1[-1][:j+1]

arr2 = arr[i:]
arr2[0] = arr2[0][j+1:]

'''
arr1 = [[1, 4, 2, 4, 7], 
        [6, 7]] 
arr2 = [[9, 2, 8]]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with numpy since each row in a the 2d array has to be of the same length.